# How do I use Uri.parse() method while testing?

Tags: android, android-room, android-espresso

I am working on an Android Project and I wanted to store the *URI* of a resource in a *Database* using **Room** Library.

Since Room does not support complex data types, therefore I created a **TypeConverter** named `stringToUri(string: String?): Uri?`.

Here is the definition of the Type Converter:

```
@TypeConverter
    fun stringToUri(string: String?): Uri? {
        return Uri.parse(string)
    }
```

Now I wanted to test the converter before using it. Therefore, I created a *TestFunciton* named `converter_uriToString_validUri_returnsString()`.

Here is the definition of the Test Function:

```
@Test
    fun testStringToUri_validString_returnsUri() {

        val expectedUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/42")    // Line 165
        val actualUri = converter.stringToUri("content://media/external/audio/media/42")

        assertEquals(expectedUri, actualUri)
    }
```

But the test fails with the following error/message:

> **Method parse in android.net.Uri not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.**
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method parse in android.net.Uri not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.
>
> at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java)

I am very much new to Android Development and this is my first project. Can you please help me through this error.

###### What I did

I created a test function that would test the TypeConverter named `uriToString(uri: Uri?): String?`.

###### What I expected

I was expecting that the TypeConverter would return the expecting string after conversion and the test funciton would pass.

###### What actually resulted

The test funciton failed with the message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException at ConverterTest.kt:165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test your `stringToUri` converter, you need to use Android's Instrumentation Testing rather than regular unit testing. Instrumentation tests run on an Android device or emulator and have access to Android-specific classes and methods.

Here's how you can create an instrumentation test for your converter:

1. Create an Android Instrumented Test class for your converter. You can do this by right-clicking on your app module in Android Studio, selecting "New" -> "Java Class," and then choosing "Android Instrumented Test."
2. In your instrumentation test class, import the necessary Android testing libraries and set up the test.

```kotlin
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class UriConverterInstrumentedTest {

    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
    private val converter = YourTypeConverter() // Replace with your actual TypeConverter

    @Test
    fun testStringToUri_validString_returnsUri() {
        val expectedUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/42")
        val actualUri = converter.stringToUri("content://media/external/audio/media/42")

        assertEquals(expectedUri, actualUri)
    }

    // Add more tests as needed

}
```

In the code above, replace `YourTypeConverter` with the actual class name of your TypeConverter.

3. To run the instrumentation test, right-click on your test class and select "Run."

Instrumentation tests are designed to work with Android-specific code and libraries, so you should be able to test your TypeConverter successfully using this approach.

Comment: One could argue that if all the converter is doing is parsing an URI via the existing android framework URI parser, the test is quite useless as-is, not to mention that it would be slower to run and will need a device/emulator to be present to run and drive the test.

I would rather see an abstraction on the Parser method and unit test it with Fake values or a mocked version that returns "valid" and "invalid" cases to see how the code that *depends* on this URI reacts in each instance.